# How to remove all data before the nth occurance of a delimiter in a String?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a string which is separated with comma. I want remove all data before my second comma along with the comma. For example:

```
Input: 1,2,3,4,5

Output: 3,4,5
```

Answer (score 2):

Just define an UDF that does that, something along these lines:

```
val dropTwoEntries = udf((s: String) => s.split(",").drop(2).mkString(","))
df.withColumn("output", dropTwoEntries(col("input")))
```